# .Net ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, linqpad7

I am getting this error trying to connect to an oracle db.  I can connect on the command line using SQLplus from the command prompt or powershell.  So I know that this machine can talk to the database.  But something is not right on the .Net side.

I'm running LinqPad 7 and using the Oracle drivers.  But get the same error that I get from plain old C# code.

Does anyone know what is the cause and solution?

[image]